# pytest: How to set global variable values in pytest test function

Tags: python, pytest

app.py below, running env = python 3.8

```
import argParse
    
#set global var 
ARGS = None
#a json data will be copied into CFG
CFG=None
# global var
PATTERN = re.compile(r'(\d{6})')

def parseCmdLineArgs():
      global ARGS
      ARGS = parser.parse_args(ARGV)
      #ARGS.arg1_value is a string
      #ARGS.arg2_val_is_jsonfile 
      CFG = json.loads(ARGS.arg2_val_is_jsonfile) #CFG["maxLen"] =100 is set

def some_func():
    msg=scan(PATTERN,CFG["maxLen"], ARGS.arg1_value)
```

pytest test_app.py:

```
import app
from app import some_func
def test_some_func():
    some_func()
```

Question: above test_some_func() fails.
How to set the global variable's (CFG, PATTERN )value from here ?

Comment: Not immediately relevant, but shouldn't `parseCmdLineArgs` be using `arg1.json_file` in place of `ARGS.json_file`? It's not clear why `ARGS` exists at all.

Comment: @chepner  corrected the code above. So, app.py received 2 cmd line params, (1) arg1 -str and arg2- a json file path. Now, How can I set those ARGS.arg1 , CFG, PATTERN for the test_func() to work is my question. Hope its clear now.

Comment: You are using far too many global variables in the first place. `some_func` should take arguments, possibly taken from the return value of `parseCmdLineArgs`.

Comment: agree @chepner. I wanted to continue this way, as there's a lot of older code harder & impossible to refactor now. Your solution works by the way. I wanted to know whether we can somehow mock these global var's values & pass function.  your solution is also a global var in the test file. By the way, i'm a beginner in pytest world...

Answer (score 1):

`some_func` uses `CFG` defined in its own global scope. You need to provide a value if you aren't calling `app.parseCmdLineArgs` to set its value.

```
import app
from app import some_func


app.CFG = {'maxlen': 100}  # for example

def test_some_func():
    some_func()
```